# How do i solve the java 7 FTP transfer in windows 8

Tags: java, windows-8, java-7

I am using windows 8 x86 and jdk_7. The code below compliles just fine without errors. When i run it gives me this exception:

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: localhost, port: 25;
   nested exception is:
java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connect
```

Now as a workaround, i tried to add this line:

```
System.setProperty("java.net.preferIPv4Stack", "true");
```

This did not solve the problem, and after hours of researching on the internet, i noticed the problem is with the jdk_7 and the firewall issues. I even tried this command

```
netsh advfirewall set global StatefulFTP disable
```

this could'nt solve the problem either.

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.*;
import javax.activation.*;

public class SendFileEmail
{
  public static void main(String [] args)
  {
     System.setProperty("java.net.preferIPv4Stack", "true");
  // Recipient's email ID needs to be mentioned.
     String to = "tmadile@gmail.com";

  // Sender's email ID needs to be mentioned
     String from = "hareitse@gmail.com";

  // Assuming you are sending email from localhost
     String host = "localhost";

  // Get system properties
     Properties properties = System.getProperties();

  // Setup mail server
     properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", host);

  // Get the default Session object.
     Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);

     try{
     // Create a default MimeMessage object.
        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);

     // Set From: header field of the header.
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));

     // Set To: header field of the header.
        message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                              new InternetAddress(to));

     // Set Subject: header field
        message.setSubject("This is the Subject Line!");

     // Create the message part 
        BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();

     // Fill the message
        messageBodyPart.setText("This is message body");

     // Create a multipar message
        Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();

     // Set text message part
        multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

     // Part two is attachment
        messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        String filename = "shh.jpg";
        DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename);
        messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
        messageBodyPart.setFileName(filename);
        multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

     // Send the complete message parts
        message.setContent(multipart );

     // Send message
        Transport.send(message);
        System.out.println("Sent message successfully....");
     }
        catch (MessagingException mex) {
           mex.printStackTrace();
        }
  }
}
```

Comment: As long as you don't run an SMTP server on localhost, it won't work.

Answer (score 1):

```
// Assuming you are sending email from localhost
String host = "localhost";
// Setup mail server
properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", host);
```

The way I read your code and your error it seems more like you are trying to send from localhost as a host, where you are in fact trying to send to a mail server at localhost at port 25. If you do not have any SMTP server running on localhost, you will get the above error. The code you provided will not start any SMTP server for you. You should probably replace host = "localhost" with what your smtp host is (and potentially other settings depending on what your smtp provider needs).

Comment: Thanks for that. I did that but now i get the exception: `com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 451 SMTP Relay Connection timeout`

Comment: That is worse though. At least it indicates that your connection goes through to your smtp server. Could it be that your provider won't allow you to relay messages through their server. It was that way for me, but after contacting my ISP and getting a login for the mail server they would allow me to send e-mails with other sender addresses than they expected. Also see if the following helps (search for 451). [link](http://www.answersthatwork.com/Download_Area/ATW_Library/Networking/Network__3-SMTP_Server_Status_Codes_and_SMTP_Error_Codes.pdf)